# Issue in retrieving the array of subdocuments from MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm trying to retrieve an array of sub-documents from the MongoDB database and I'm getting the result, but I'm getting the subdocument label which I don't want.

Eg:

I'm getting

```
[{"bills":[{"_id":"64b6d9a71dd7cfdb0aba40c0","title":"Month1"},{"_id":"62b6d9a71dd7cfdb0aba40c0","title":"Month2"}]
```

Required:

```
[{"_id":"64b6d9a71dd7cfdb0aba40c0","title":"Month1"},{"_id":"62b6d9a71dd7cfdb0aba40c0","title":"Month2"}]
```

I want the bills tag to be removed

The code I have so far is:

```
const billsList = await record.find({_id:new ObjectId(billId)},{projection:{_id:0,bills:1}}).toArray();
```

How do I fix this.

Comment: like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RfbvSdz6UCI)?

Answer (score 0):

You can promotes the embedded document(s)(`bills` in your case) using [`$replaceRoot`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/#-replaceroot-with-a-document-nested-in-an-array) and `$unwind`.

MongoDB aggregation pipeline stages:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$bills"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$bills"
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OctVp33cxIl)

Input:

```js
[
  {
    "bills": [
      {
        "_id": "64b6d9a71dd7cfdb0aba40c0",
        "title": "Month1"
      },
      {
        "_id": "62b6d9a71dd7cfdb0aba40c0",
        "title": "Month2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Output:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": "64b6d9a71dd7cfdb0aba40c0",
    "title": "Month1"
  },
  {
    "_id": "62b6d9a71dd7cfdb0aba40c0",
    "title": "Month2"
  }
]
```

---

Mongoose example:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import util from 'util';
import { config } from '../../config';

mongoose.set('debug', true);
console.log(mongoose.version);

const recordSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    bills: [{ title: String }],
});
const Record = mongoose.model('Record', recordSchema);

(async function main() {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(config.MONGODB_URI);
        // await Promise.all([Record].map((m) => m.collection.drop()));
        // seed
        const [r1] = await Record.create([
            { bills: [{ title: 'Month1' }, { title: 'Month2' }] },
            { bills: [{ title: 'a' }, { title: 'b' }] },
        ]);
        // test
        const r = await Record.aggregate()
            .match({ _id: r1?._id })
            .unwind('$bills')
            .replaceRoot('$bills');

        console.log(util.inspect(r, false, null));
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    } finally {
        await mongoose.connection.close();
    }
})();
```

Logs:

```
7.3.4
Mongoose: records.insertOne({ bills: [ { title: 'Month1', _id: ObjectId("64b74da6b5e13a759dc4fb22") }, { title: 'Month2', _id: ObjectId("64b74da6b5e13a759dc4fb23") } ], _id: ObjectId("64b74da6b5e13a759dc4fb21"), __v: 0}, {})
Mongoose: records.insertOne({ bills: [ { title: 'a', _id: ObjectId("64b74da6b5e13a759dc4fb25") }, { title: 'b', _id: ObjectId("64b74da6b5e13a759dc4fb26") } ], _id: ObjectId("64b74da6b5e13a759dc4fb24"), __v: 0}, {})
Mongoose: records.aggregate([ { '$match': { _id: new ObjectId("64b74da6b5e13a759dc4fb21") } }, { '$unwind': '$bills' }, { '$replaceRoot': { newRoot: '$bills' } }], {})
[
  { title: 'Month1', _id: new ObjectId("64b74da6b5e13a759dc4fb22") },
  { title: 'Month2', _id: new ObjectId("64b74da6b5e13a759dc4fb23") }
]
```